# inspect.getmodule returns None for import hooks

Tags: python, python-import, import-hooks

I am creating a runtime module in my python code similar to

```
string_code = """
import existing_module

a = "my_string"
existing_module.register(a)
"""

mod = ModuleType("mymodule")
sys.modules["mymodule"] = mod
exec(string_code, mod.__dict__)
```

Inside the existing_module I have code which checks if the caller is a module

```
def register(a: str):
    caller = inspect.stack()[1]
    caller_module = inspect.getmodule(caller[0])
    assert caller_module is not None
```

Since I am calling the existing_module from a runtime module, I expected the caller_module to be  not None. However, I am hitting that assert. Not sure why.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Not sure if `inspect.getmodule` can guess from inside a string source.